# What do we call a person who is really smooth at talking?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people are really good at conversations and they can run a conversation perfectly without having to reach for words. They always find the right words to say in any situation and as a result, people enjoy their conversations. What is that person called in English?

Comment: *Fluent*? *Eloquent*?

Comment: Try *raconteur*.

Comment: @Robusto I would suggest that *raconteurs* are more noted for their enthusiasm at spilling a yarn, and not necessarily for their erudition. I once had a Polish landlord who kept his lodgers enthralled with stories of his escape from Poland to join the British army in Italy during WW2. (He'd been at Monte Cassino.) But his tales were made even more entertaining by his quaint application of English grammar.

Comment: @WS2: OP said nothing about erudition. He did,  however,  use the words "good at conversations" and "people enjoy their conversations." The "right" words don't have to be esoteric.

Answer (score 2):

**"articulate"** is an adjective for those who can express themselves easily, clearly and effectively.

> - [articulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/articulate) (adj) expressing oneself readily, clearly, and effectively

Answer (score 2):

I'd call that person a "[smooth talker](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/smooth-talker)", or maybe "silver tongued" or just "slick"...

[Smooth talker synonyms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/smooth_talker/synonyms/phrase) — Power Thesaurus

[Another word for smooth talking](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/smooth-talking.html) — Word Hippo

Answer (score 1):

Not looking very far, you simply call such a person "a smooth talking man/boy/women/girl/…".

- A smooth-talking man talks very confidently in a way that is likely to persuade people,…

Both the spellings "smooth-talking" and "smooth talking" are found.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the title only- *smooth at talking*, I would have answered a *raconteur*.
From Merriam-Webster: :  one who excels in telling anecdotes :  storyteller
However, extending that to smoothness in dialogue, there are several excellent suggestions above.
And as the OP has highlighted "enjoyment of the conversation," which is not likely to result solely from optimal word choices, but also from the art of delivery, I would say the description that fits is either
*a most articulate raconteur*, or *eloquent conversationalist.*

Comment: +1 to both Decapitated Soul and Centaurus as I borrowed their answers to flesh out my own.

Answer (score 0):

A wordsmith
word·smith /ˈwərdˌsmiTH/ (noun): a skilled user of words.

Comment: You need to cite the source of your definition.